Problem with enumeration in Texlive 2023
In older versions of Texlive  the following code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
Έστω η παραβολή $y=4x^2$ και μία ευθεία $(\varepsilon)$ που διέρχεται απ' την εστία της $\mathrm{E}$ και τη τέμνει στα σημεία $\mathrm{A}$ και $\mathrm{B}$. Αν $\Gamma$ και $\Delta$ οι προβολές των  $\mathrm{A}$ και $\mathrm{B}$ αντίστοιχα πάνω στη διευθετούσα της παραβολής και $\mathrm{M}$ το μέσον του $\Gamma \Delta$, τότε:

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item να υπολογιστούν οι συντεταγμένες των $\mathrm{A}$, $\mathrm{B}$, $\Gamma$, $\Delta$ και $\mathrm{M}$ συναρτήσει της τεταγμένης του $\mathrm{A}$.
    
    \item να δειχθεί ότι η αρχή των αξόνων είναι το σημείο τομής του τραπεζίου $\mathrm{AB} \Gamma \Delta$.
    
    \item να δειχθεί ότι η γωνία $mathrm{AMB}$ είναι ορθή και ότι το $\mathrm{ME}$ είναι ύψος του τριγώνου $\mathrm{AMB}$.
    
    \item $\Gamma \mathrm{E} \Delta$ είναι ορθή. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

would produce

Upgrading to Texlive 2023 a couple of days ago, I get the following

The question is why? What can I do to retain the accent in the enumeration?
I am running Texstudio with Texlive 2023 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Addendum: Of all the logs, this one
Missing character: There is no ʹ (U+02B9) in font GFS Didot Regular/OT:script=grek;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
keeps appearing over and over again.

Of would be useful if you also provided the logs as well

OK, it's quite long. How do I add it?

Add it as text to your question. The main thing to look for is char øs missing in font. Not at pc so cannot test code

@daleif Yeah, it says: Missing character: There is no ʹ (U+02B9) in font GFS Didot Regular/OT:script=grek;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!

So either the font changed or the programme was better at reporting missing stuff.

Checking on Overleaf, it works in texive 2018  and fails in texlive 2019 or later

in 2018 you get βʹ  where the ' is U+0374 GREEK NUMERAL SIGN  not U+02B9 MODIFIER LETTER PRIME

@daleif no I think the macros changed

Off-topic: You seem to like to have upright rather than slanted glyphs to denote math-roman symbols. If this impression is correct, I suggest you load the unicode-math package and issue a suitable \setmathfont directive with the option math-style=upright. This will free you from having to provide all those \mathrm wrapper directives.

I'm not sure why gloss-greek.ldf changed U+0374 into U+02B9. You can easily revert it.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd\anw@true{\renewrobustcmd\anw@print{ʹ}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
Έστω η παραβολή $y=4x^2$ και μία ευθεία $(\varepsilon)$ που διέρχεται απ' την εστία της $\mathrm{E}$ και τη τέμνει στα σημεία $\mathrm{A}$ και $\mathrm{B}$. Αν $\Gamma$ και $\Delta$ οι προβολές των  $\mathrm{A}$ και $\mathrm{B}$ αντίστοιχα πάνω στη διευθετούσα της παραβολής και $\mathrm{M}$ το μέσον του $\Gamma \Delta$, τότε:

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item να υπολογιστούν οι συντεταγμένες των $\mathrm{A}$, $\mathrm{B}$, $\Gamma$, $\Delta$ και $\mathrm{M}$ συναρτήσει της τεταγμένης του $\mathrm{A}$.
    
    \item να δειχθεί ότι η αρχή των αξόνων είναι το σημείο τομής του τραπεζίου $\mathrm{AB} \Gamma \Delta$.
    
    \item να δειχθεί ότι η γωνία $mathrm{AMB}$ είναι ορθή και ότι το $\mathrm{ME}$ είναι ύψος του τριγώνου $\mathrm{AMB}$.
    
    \item $\Gamma \mathrm{E} \Delta$ είναι ορθή. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Avoid loading xltxtra. It used to be recommended a few years ago, nowadays it could be even harmful.

and this avoids using a package from a very unreliable source

@DavidCarlisle Very useful package, isn't it?

@egreg If I do not load the package xltxtra, then the logo \Xetex does not load. Any workaround?

@Tolaso \usepackage{metalogo}

The problem is the font, if you use Brill  which is an excellent font for Greek, there is no issue either with XeLaTeX  or LaTeX. The ldf file has correctly separated the two, as in a list it must use the numeral sign. It will make life easier with screen readers down the line...

@yannisl I'm not sure what you mean: gloss-greek.ldf now has U+02B9 MODIFIER LETTER PRIME instead of U+0374 GREEK NUMERAL SIGN that it used to have. I believe that the latter is the intended character in this context.

@egreg  I dont seem to find  it in the gloss-greek.ldf generated by polyglossia. I think is part of the font internal routines.  I just modified the example to use Brill and it worked without any issue.

@yannisl Brill has both glyphs, but their shapes are quite different and I contend that the default, U+02B9, doesn’t seem right.

In texlive 2018 you get βʹ where the ' is U+0374 GREEK NUMERAL SIGN not  ʹ  which is U+02B9 MODIFIER LETTER PRIME which is produced (and does not work) in texlive 2019 and later.
Ideally you would trace where the mapping has changed in the Greek setup, but it's a bit Greek for me to follow so simpler is to tell xelatex to typeset both primes the same way using \newunicodechar)

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ʹ}{'}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
Έστω η παραβολή $y=4x^2$ και μία ευθεία $(\varepsilon)$ που διέρχεται απ' την εστία της $\mathrm{E}$ και τη τέμνει στα σημεία $\mathrm{A}$ και $\mathrm{B}$. Αν $\Gamma$ και $\Delta$ οι προβολές των  $\mathrm{A}$ και $\mathrm{B}$ αντίστοιχα πάνω στη διευθετούσα της παραβολής και $\mathrm{M}$ το μέσον του $\Gamma \Delta$, τότε:

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item να υπολογιστούν οι συντεταγμένες των $\mathrm{A}$, $\mathrm{B}$, $\Gamma$, $\Delta$ και $\mathrm{M}$ συναρτήσει της τεταγμένης του $\mathrm{A}$.
    
    \item να δειχθεί ότι η αρχή των αξόνων είναι το σημείο τομής του τραπεζίου $\mathrm{AB} \Gamma \Delta$.
    
    \item να δειχθεί ότι η γωνία $mathrm{AMB}$ είναι ορθή και ότι το $\mathrm{ME}$ είναι ύψος του τριγώνου $\mathrm{AMB}$.
    
    \item $\Gamma \mathrm{E} \Delta$ είναι ορθή. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


The problem is the font, if you use Brill  which is an excellent font for Greek, there is no issue either with XeLaTeX  or LaTeX. The ldf file has correctly separated the two, as in a list it must use the numeral sign. It will make life easier with screen readers down the line and the tagging project?

@yannisl well yes it's clearly font related in that if a font has both characters then either will work, but if it only has one of them, then only one will work.  I don't know Greek but I assume? that the old value GREEK NUMERAL SIGN is more correct in this use than the new MODIFIER LETTER PRIME ? in either case the package could check whether the font has the glyph and choose a prime symbol that is in the font.
